# How would you create a reusable component for this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, code-reuse, reusability

lets say you get a design youre asked to implement in android: [image]

How would you build this so that its somehow reusable, I mean with models,  xml-layouts, custom layouts written programmatically etc.. I'm curious how this would be solved according to some best practices.

Best regards

Comment: it is a custom listview item, in which you can control views based on some logic, you can create a raw containing all widgets with all states in a separate xml and use it with custom Adapter

Comment: If every one of these views has different info and calls different functions and displays different data, then trying to use one reusable layout for all of them is likely to cause headaches. But some parts (such as the profile pic and little icons on the right) are the same in all of them, so that could be one smaller layout that you insert into the bigger layout. So some parts are reusable. But it depends on whether this is similar data displayed in different ways, or different data in each of them.

Comment: Even though this looks like a list I think the best way would be actually to use fragments in this case as the UI seems very different in each case and if you don't have many elements a ListView doesnt offer anything over a simple LInearLayout.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
The data it'll be populated with are actually different, I mean, it's from different kind of objects depending on some conditions. It really is a mess which have caused me some headaches now when I've tried to make a full reusable component for this whole thing :)